# Hangfire 1.7.8 service Dotnetcore 3.1 high memory usage with many instances of TimerQueueTimer

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services, hangfire

[Memory profiler data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nfXkq.png)

I have a service written in DotnetCore 3.1 with Hangfire 1.7.8.
I see unusually high memory usage and most of the memory is consumed by TimerQueueTimer objects, although I have not explicitly initialized any Timer.

Since I have created originally in Dotnetcore 2.2 it is using the old service structure like this:

```
internal class HangFireService : ServiceBase
{
}
```

Jobs added like this on service start and as well when tasks finished:

```
if(!_hangfireHelper.GetJobs(typeof(GenericTask), taskName).Any())
            {
                BackgroundJob.Schedule<GenericTask>(d => d.RunTask(null), TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));
            }
```

How can I reduce the timer usage?

Answer (score 1):

Finally turns out that nothing to do with Hangfire but the root cause of high memory usages was because of the Serilog.

I created a dummy log class and I injected to all of my services and all of the TimerQueueTimer objects gone. Here is another memoryprofiler image:

[Memory sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wroRo.png)

Serilog usage was the following:

```
public Logger Logger()
       {

            var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(_configuration)
                .CreateLogger();
            return log;
        }
```

usage:

```
using( var log = Logger())
{
   log.LogInformation(...)
}
```

Somehow serilog did not dispose timer objects...

Comment: Hi! Serilog `Logger`s should be effectively singletons - creating and initializing the whole logging pipeline for each log event is expensive. Although Serilog will generally dispose the resources it uses, some of these might take some time to be completely cleaned up by the underlying system.

Comment: Yes I know but it grew up from 75MB to 1,2GB without disposing timers... Removing Serilog and added my light sql logger it kept the original 75 MB memory for days.

Comment: Might be a problem with one of the sinks you're using - will need some more investigation. Using singleton `Logger`s is still highly recommended, though.